# Post JS variables to Django view and display as context variables in separate template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to achieve three things:

1. collect some user input using standard HTML forms in one template (`questions.html` below);
2. post that input to my `views.py`; and finally
3. display that input as context variables in a separate template (`results.html` below).

Once I get this to work, I'll do some processing of the input in the `views.py` before passing some output on as a context variable - but first I need to figure out the basic principle of moving from user input in one template --> views.py --> context variables in another template.

Also, I'm deliberately doing this without touching any database, since I don't want to save any user data.

Here's what I have for my `questions.html`, collecting age and level of education:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit_answers').submit(function (event) {
            var user_age = document.getElementById("age-choice").value;
            var user_education = document.getElementById("education-choice").value;
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"{% url 'results' %}",
                data : {
                    'age': user_age,
                    'education': user_education,
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
            })
        }
    )});
</script>

<p>Please answer the following questions:</p>

<p>What is your age?</p>
<form action="" method="GET" id="age-dropdown">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="age-choice">
        <option value="18-30">18-30</option>
        <option value="30-40">30-40</option>
        <option value="40-50">40-50</option>
        <option value="50-65">50-65</option>
        <option value="65-100">Over 65</option>
    </select>
</form>

<p>What is your highest level of education?</p>
<form action="" method="GET" id="education-dropdown">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select class="browser-default custom-select" id="education-choice">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="GCSE">GCSE</option>
        <option value="A-level">A-level</option>
        <option value="University">University</option>
        <option value="Postgraduate">Postgraduate</option>
    </select>
</form>

<form id="submit_answers" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit_answers" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('questions/', QuestionsView.as_view(), name='questions'),
    path('results/', ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
]
```

And here's my `views.py`:

```
class QuestionsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'questions.html'

class ResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'results.html'

    def answers(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            context = {}
            context["age"] = request.POST['age']
            context["education"] = request.POST['education']
            return context
```

And `results.html`:

```
<p>Results:</p>
Age: {{ age }} <br />
Education: {{ education }}
```

With the above, I get this in the Terminal:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /results/
Method Not Allowed: /results/
[03/Dec/2019 15:43:22] "POST /results/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
Method Not Allowed (POST): /questions/
Method Not Allowed: /questions/
[03/Dec/2019 15:43:22] "POST /questions/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily call the method "answers". It needs to be "get" or "post", presumably in your case "post"; and then you don't need to check the request.method within the method, it'll always be POST.

Comment: However this still won't work because none of your HTML form elements have `name` attributes, so the browser won't send any data for them.

Comment: Really though this whole approach should be reduced to a single view using a Django form; in other words, a FormView.

Comment: And finally I don't understand what the JS is doing here. You post via Ajax and ignore the response, so you'll never see the result. Why do you need Ajax at all?

Comment: I agree. jQuery Ajax is going to make an asynchronous call to the result endpoint. The data should be there correctly (even without `name`s) because of the jQuery, but the main page isn’t going to navigate or load the view code. This really doesn’t need jQuery or even JS. 

I don’t know what is causing a “Method not Allowed” error though.

Comment: @Matthias that's because the ResultsView doesn't define a `post` method, as I mentioned in the first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielRoseman and @Matthias for their suggestions. I followed Daniel's suggestion to switch to forms, and Matthias's suggestion to drop the JS, as follows:

First the form, `forms.py`:

```
EDUCATION_CHOICES= [
    ('none', 'None'),
    ('gcse', 'GCSE'),
    ('alevel', 'A-level'),
    ('university', 'University'),
    ]

class UserInputForm(forms.Form):
 age = forms.IntegerField(label='Enter your age')
 education = forms.CharField(label='What is your highest level of education?', widget=forms.Select(choices=EDUCATION_CHOICES))
```

Then the form template, `userinputform.html`:

```
<form action="/results/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And the `views.py` where the results template now has a post method that also returns the context:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class ResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'results.html'

    def post(self, request):
        context = {}
        context["age"] = request.POST['age']
        context["education"] = request.POST['education']
        return render(request, 'results.html', context)

def userinputform(request):
    form = UserInputForm()
    return render(request, 'userinputform.html', {'form':form});
```

And finally, `results.html`:

```
<p>Results:</p>
Age: {{ age }} <br />
Education: {{ education }}
```